# Why would want to get back a MvcHtmlString instead of writing to the response stream?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have read this question ([Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)) and understand ***what*** Html.Partial and Html.Action do.

But I am trying to understand ***why*** these were introduced. Could you please explain a scenario where I would want to get back a MvcHtmlString instead of writing it out to the response stream? I am sure there is a big use case for this.

Thanks!

Comment: @Andrews Barber 's answer was correct and I was reading the question differently than he was.  I'm not sure why he deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having MvcHtmlString gives you more flexibility. You may modify it before using or store it to avoid complex rerendering.

Comment: Exactly. Also, it allows a nicer syntax when calling it from Razor. You can do this: @Html.Partial(...) rather than @{Html.RenderPartial(...);}