# Is there an overhead with @Html.RenderPartial or @Html.Partial in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just asked a question about use of these. They were suggested to me as a means to include text ( paragraphs of text ) into a web page. VERY STATIC text that I don't want to fill up the view with.

My question is. Which of these two should I use and also is there an overhead to using them. I thought views were compiled just once. How about if I include these files. Does that mean that every time I view a page then it has to go get the file.

Comment: How about a resource file instead?

Comment: Can you explain what a resource file is?  Thanks

Comment: It is .net's way of managing static "resources" like strings. http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+resource+files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, have a read through [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)
and then you can read this post,
http://5pm.zwares.com/post/1172669451/asp-net-mvc-performance-html-renderpartial-vs

in summary, the post contains this bit of useful information from Phil Haack

> Html.RenderAction will render the
>   result directly to the Response (which
>   is more efficient if the action
>   returns a large amount of HTML)
>   whereas Html.Action returns a string
>   with the result.

Comment: I tried the following: Line 116:    @if (Model.RowKey == "Objectives") {
Line 117:        @{Html.RenderPartial("objectives.cshtml");}
Line 118:    } but this give me an error: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Comment: It's because you don't put a block of code in a block of code.  It should look like `@if (Model.RowKey == "Objectives") { Html.RenderPartial(""); }`  Instead of what your code probably looks like `@if (Model.RowKey == "Objectives") {  @{Html.RenderPartial("");} }`