# RenderPartial not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, renderpartial

I have a simple partial view which returns (renders) a list of synonyms of a given word. Then I'd like to use this partial view inside another view and I use `@Html.RenderPartial("SynonymFinder", new { word = "Something" })` inside my view. But I get this error:

CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

This is the simplest scenario. I even removed the parameters and used `@Html.RenderPartial("SynonymFinder")`, but still the same problem. What's wrong?

Comment: For more information on the differences between `Partial` and `RenderPartial` see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction/5248218#5248218

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MVC  3 you should use:

```
@Html.Partial("SynonymFinder", new ViewDataDictionary { { word = "Something" } })
```

Note that the 2nd parameter is of type `ViewDataDictionary`. If you don't pass it explicitly like that, the helper will use the overload that takes an `object` as the 2nd parameter and uses it as a Model instead of as route values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model with the field word

```
public class SynonymFinderModel
{
    public string Word {get; set;}
}
```

Then, in your view, you have

```
@Html.Partial("SynonymFinder", new SynonymFinderModel { Word = "something"})
```