# When I call html.renderpartial do I need to specify my model on the first line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to use renderpartial but I'm not so clear on the way it is used. If I just call render partial then is any model sent to that? I want to use the HTML helpers. Is there any difference between using those in renderpartial and in the main razor view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the view actually uses a model and you don't provide any, it just end up having a null Model object (so lots of Null Object Reference Exception).

Just go with

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_partialView", PartialViewModel); }
```

or:

```
@Html.Partial("_partialView", PartialViewModel)
```

The differences between the two are indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction).

HTH, M.