# RenderPartial not rendering inside of div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, mvccontrib-grid, html.renderpartial

Hi I'm having some issues understanding how MVC 3 and razor work.  Basically, I have a view that's rendered with Html.Render partial.  basically, I'm trying to render the contents or a partial view inside of div like so.

```
<div id="mydiv.id">
@{Html.RenderPartial("_BankAccountGrid", Model.CheckAccounts);}
</div>


@if (Model.Any())
{        

        @{Html.Grid(Model).Columns(c =>
        {
                c.For(a => Html.ActionLink(
                    "Edit",
                    "EditBankAccountDetails",
                    "UserManagement",
                    new { Id = a.Id }, new { id = "modalEdit" }));
                c.For(a => a.AccountName);
                c.For(a => a.AccountNumber);
                c.For(a => a.RoutingNumber);
                c.For(a => a.BankName);
                c.For(a => a.CheckAccountType);
                c.For(a => a.AccountType_Id).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.version).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.IsDefault).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.User_Id).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.Id).Visible(false);
            }).Render();
        }      
}
```

However when I look at the DOM in firebug the Table is ALWAYS rendered outside of the div in just a table element.  I've tried this as well.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_BankAccountGrid", Model.CheckAccounts);}


@if (Model.Any())
{        
    <div id="accounts.grid.div">
        @{Html.Grid(Model).Columns(c =>
        {
                c.For(a => Html.ActionLink(
                    "Edit",
                    "EditBankAccountDetails",
                    "UserManagement",
                    new { Id = a.Id }, new { id = "modalEdit" }));
                c.For(a => a.AccountName);
                c.For(a => a.AccountNumber);
                c.For(a => a.RoutingNumber);
                c.For(a => a.BankName);
                c.For(a => a.CheckAccountType);
                c.For(a => a.AccountType_Id).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.version).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.IsDefault).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.User_Id).Visible(false);
                c.For(a => a.Id).Visible(false);
            }).Render();
        }
    </div>
}
```

.. but to no avail.  Is there something I'm missing?

If I'm not clear enough or you just need more info please just ask instead of voting down.

Comment: the issue could be that you are not closing the div properly. Use '</div>' and have a try...

Comment: no that wasn't it.  Sorry copy paste error.  I fixed the div now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using MvcContrib.Grid. You should have mentioned that in your question. First make sure that you have downloaded the latest version (the one made for ASP.NET MVC 3, because the older version for ASP.NET MVC 2 doesn't work well with Razor).

Then try like this:

```
@if (Model.Any())
{        
    @(Html
        .Grid(Model)
        .Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Custom(
                @<text>
                    @Html.ActionLink(
                        "Edit", 
                        "EditBankAccountDetails", 
                        "UserManagement", 
                        new { Id = item.Id }, 
                        new { id = "modalEdit" }
                    )
                 </text>
            ).Named("");

            c.For(a => a.AccountName);
            c.For(a => a.AccountNumber);
            c.For(a => a.RoutingNumber);
            c.For(a => a.BankName);
            c.For(a => a.CheckAccountType);
            c.For(a => a.AccountType_Id).Visible(false);
            c.For(a => a.version).Visible(false);
            c.For(a => a.IsDefault).Visible(false);
            c.For(a => a.User_Id).Visible(false);
            c.For(a => a.Id).Visible(false);
        })
     )
}
```

Notice that I am using a `Custom` column for the `ActionLink` and that I am no longer calling the `.Render` method on the grid.

Comment: Where should I get the newest version ?  I'm running version version 2.0.95.0 which I got from Nuget. However, this line c.Custom in the code you posted can't be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Html.RenderPartial writes directly to the response.  I think what you want here is Html.Partial.

```
<div id="mydiv.id">
@Html.Partial("_BankAccountGrid", Model.CheckAccounts)
<div>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction) for more detail