# Razor @{ ... } vs @ calling RenderPartial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to understand why when I do this in my view, I get an error

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", Model);
```

**Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.**

**Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments**

But when I do this, the partial renders fine

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", Model);
}
```

Does anyone know why the first example fails?

Comment: Check this answer.. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction

Comment: The one liner call is mostly to output data (such as @DateTime.Now) or   pure C# logic (such as @model.ID != 0? yes : no). Block codes are for API processing, such as calling a partial view or other most sophisticated operations. Notice that the error states about writing a Helper to the page.

Comment: Duplicate. This is essentially the same as question linked by @Chandu.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'd say that it is similar but not identical. In terms of finding a question you might not think that something comparing partial and renderpartial has anything to do with why somethign needs to be in a block or not...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically the fact that this format...

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", Model)
```

... is used for functions that don't return `void`, since RenderPartial does return `void`, you get that error.

Instead, in this block, it's just code execution (that will internally make the write call):

```
    @{    
Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", Model); 
}
```

You can alternativelly call

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartial")
```

... which does return the string.