# Difference between RenderPartial and Partial method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

I have 3 questions.

1-Whats is exactly difference between RenderPartial and Partial method?

1-Whats is exactly difference between RenderAction and Partial RenderPartial ?

2-What is the RendePage method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**RenderPartial** writes the result directly to the response, technically speaking, directly into the calling object's TextWriter. RenderPartial is a bit faster and hence developers prefer using it inside the looping constructs and related scenarios.

**Partial** on the other hand returns the HTML markup as string, which buffers the content. It achieves by creating and using a separate TextWriter.

**RenderAction** Invokes the specified child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view. In other words allows you call Action from view.

**RenderPage** Renders the specified view (identified by path and file name rather than by view name) directly to the response stream, like Html.RenderPartial().

Everything depends on situation.

Comment: from controller?or from the view?

Comment: @Shahrooz Jafari Yes, call action from view and action defined in controller