# Can I have variable in HTML.PartialRender()?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, html

Can I have Something like:

```
 @{HTML.PartialRender(variable);} // where variable will be a path of a file
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a variable as the path parameter when the view is being rendered on the server.

```
@{
    string path = "foo/bar"; // a path which the view engine can locate
}

<div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial( path ); }

    @* OR *@

    @Html.Partial( path )
</div>
```

Since the question is also tagged with JavaScript, I will point out that you can't mix Razor (server) rendering with client (JavaScript) execution. However, you can easily invoke a controller using AJAX (and pass it whatever data you want) and that controller can return a rendered view.

See also: [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Comment: So, I can't use Javascript function, to return a string path to a Razor, right? That, also mean that I can't use a "path" instance variable, where I will be getting a path from JavaScript.

Comment: Correct. However, you could pass your JavaScript variable to a controller with an AJAX request and have the controller return you a different/customized view.

Comment: You should update your question with the code you tried (or open another question).

Answer (score 0):

[These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) are Overload for RenderPartial

```
     1.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String)
```

> Renders the specified partial view by using the specified HTML helper.

```
     2. RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String, Object)
```

> Renders the specified
>              partial view, passing it a copy of the current ViewDataDictionary
>               object, but with the Model property set to the specified model.

```
     3. RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String, ViewDataDictionary)
```

> Renders the
>               specified partial view, replacing its ViewData property with the
>               specified ViewDataDictionary object.

```
     4. RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String, Object,
```

> ```
>      ViewDataDictionary)  Renders the specified partial view, replacing
>             the partial view's ViewData property with the specified
>             ViewDataDictionary object and setting the Model property of the view
>             data to the specified model.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use overload:  `RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String, Object)`

Eg.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", new { filePath = model.FilePath});}
```