# Difference between Html.RenderPartial and Html.Render

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.renderpartial

I am new to asp.net and im have a page that i want to show as a partial view.
The page is in a div tag ,like this `<div> Html.RenderPartial("view",Model)</div>`
and im doing the same thing with Html.Render but it works just with RenderPartial.

Does anyone have any idea why,and what es the difference?? i know that Renderpartial ist better for Image and etc.. but is there another difference??? 
Thx very much :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248218/51) should give you what you are looking for (copying relevant sections):

Html.Partial returns a string, Html.RenderPartial calls Write internally, and returns void. The usage (using Razor syntax):

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName");  }
```

Will do exactly the same. You can store the output of Html.Partial in a variable, or return it from a function. You cannot do this with Html.RenderPartial. The result will be written to the Response stream during the execution.