# MVC 4 - how do I pass model data to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm building a profile page that will have a number of sections that relate to a particular model (Tenant) - AboutMe, MyPreferences - those kind of things. Each one of those sections is going to be a partial view, to allow for partial page updates using AJAX.

When I click on an `ActionResult` in the TenantController I'm able to create a strongly typed view and the model data is passed to the view fine. I can't achieve this with partial views.

I've created a partial view `_TenantDetailsPartial`:

```
@model LetLord.Models.Tenant
<div class="row-fluid">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName) // this displays UserName when not in IF
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UserName) // this displays nothing
</div>
```

I then have a view `MyProfile` that will render mentioned partial views:

```
@model LetLord.Models.Tenant
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 well-border">
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/Tenants/_TenantDetailsPartial.cshtml", 
         new ViewDataDictionary<LetLord.Models.Tenant>())
    </div>
</div>
```

If I wrap the code inside the DIV in `_TenantDetailsPartial` inside `@if(model != null){}` nothing gets displayed on the page, so I'm guessing there is an empty model being passed to the view.

How come when I create a strongly typed view from an `ActionResult` the user in the 'session' gets passed to the view? How can pass the user in the 'session' to a partial view that is not created from an `ActionResult`? If I'm missing something about the concept, please explain.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're not actually passing the model to the Partial, you're passing a `new ViewDataDictionary<LetLord.Models.Tenant>()`. Try this:

```
@model LetLord.Models.Tenant
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 well-border">
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/Tenants/_TenantDetailsPartial.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I genuinely tried that earlier and it didn't work! I mustn't have rebuilt my solution... Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 15):

Also, this could make it works:

```
@{
Html.RenderPartial("your view", your_model, ViewData);
}
```

or

```
@{
Html.RenderPartial("your view", your_model);
}
```

For more information on RenderPartial and similar HTML helpers in MVC see [this popular StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction?lq=1)

Answer (score 14):

I know question is specific to MVC4. But since we are way past MVC4 and if anyone looking for **ASP.NET Core**, you can use:

```
<partial name="_My_Partial" model="Model.MyInfo" />
```

Answer (score 7):

**Three ways to pass model data to partial view (there may be more)**

This is view page

**Method One** Populate at view

```
@{    
    PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel ctry1 = new PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel();
    ctry1.CountryName="India";
    ctry1.ID=1;    

    PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel ctry2 = new PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel();
    ctry2.CountryName="Africa";
    ctry2.ID=2;

    List<PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel> CountryList = new List<PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel>();
    CountryList.Add(ctry1);
    CountryList.Add(ctry2);    

}

@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViewTest.cshtml",CountryList );
}
```

**Method Two**
Pass Through ViewBag

```
@{
    var country = (List<PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel>)ViewBag.CountryList;
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViewTest.cshtml",country );
}
```

**Method Three**
pass through model

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialViewTest.cshtml",Model.country );
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please put partial view code as well. i am not getting anything when used second method to pass value to partial view

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla I think var countries = ViewBag.CountryList as List<PartialViewTestSOl.Models.CountryModel>  can give you the value