# When I render a partial view my Model is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to Render a view which consists of just a DropDownList inside another View in ASP.NET MVC but for some reason the Model is Null. I think it's because I am only calling the view and the Controller isn't being called at all. Where am I going wrong? maybe my phone approach is incorrect.

**Dropbox View**

```
@model MyWatch.Models.Countries
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "CountrySearch";
    Layout = null;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countries, new SelectList(Model.countries.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.name, Value = s.code })));
    }
    else
    {
        Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countries, new SelectList(new List<String>()));
    }
}
```

**Main View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("Search/CountrySearch");}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult CountrySearch()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Alex Combe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MyWatch\\MyWatch\\App_Data\\CountryList.json"))
            {
                string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Countries countries = new Countries();
                countries.countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Country>>(json);
                return View(countries);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return View(new Countries());
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace MyWatch.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public SelectList selectList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Countries
    {
        public IList<Country> countries;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you're not passing your model to the partial view, e.g.  `Html.RenderPartial("Search/CountrySearch", Model);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 4 - how do I pass model data to a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148103/mvc-4-how-do-i-pass-model-data-to-a-partial-view)

Comment: Instead of RenderPartial, use the Action() method. RenderPartial won't pass though the controller, it goes straight to the view.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to render a view directly, you should call controller action first. Use `Html.RenderAction` instead;

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @{Html.RenderAction("CountrySearch","Search");}
</div>
```

And return `PartialView` instead of `View`;

```
return PartialView(countries);
```

Also, `DropDownListFor` first parameter should be selected item.

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.countries.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.name, Value = s.code })));
```

And change your model too;

```
public class Countries
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public IList<Country> countries;
}
```

And be sure about that `CountryList.json` has valid data for your model.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much to both of you for your feedback. I've made the changes you have suggested but now I'm getting the following InnerException when I try to render the Register Page:

`InnerException {"The controller for path '/Account/Register' was not found or does not implement IController."} System.Exception {System.Web.HttpException}`

Comment: @AlexanderCombe that error appears to be unrelated to the code here, you should make a separate question about it, with relevant code.

Comment: As @ADyson described, it is unrelevant with this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.Partial` and `@Html.RenderPartial` methods are not meant to call the Controller’s Action method, instead these methods will directly populate the Partial View's markup from the given model and render it. If no model is passed, then it will just render the view markup as if the model was empty.

If you want to use RenderPartial, you need to pass it a model object directly in the method, as the second parameter - see the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29

e.g. `@Html.RenderPartial("Search/CountrySearch", yourModelObject)`

If you want to do it via your controller action, you have to call `@Html.RenderAction("CountrySearch", "Search")` instead, and have the `CountrySearch` method end with `return PartialView` instead of `return View`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback