# How to pass value from PartialView to View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, controller

I have a partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ASP.Models.Staff>  

<select class="form-control">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option>@item.Time</option>
    }
</select>
```

How can I pass `@item.Time` to another view in same controller ?

Comment: use the `@Html.RenderPartial` helper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 4 - how do I pass model data to a partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148103/mvc-4-how-do-i-pass-model-data-to-a-partial-view)