# Html.Partial not working under if statement

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following loc in one of my view pages:

```
@* Html.Partial("Form")*@

  @{
    var role = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Role"]);
    if (role == 2)
    {
        Html.Partial("Form");
    }
}
```

The `Html.Partial("Form")`  works fine when its outside any if statement and renders everything fine.

But when Inside an `if` block it renders nothing, if statements is hit, it’s true, debugger eves reads the function and goes to the `Form Partial view` and goes through every line in it but at the end there is not output on the page.

Kindly help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use RenderPartial method when you are inside a code block.

```
Html.RenderPartial("Form");
```

Html.Partial returns an HtmlString which would be rendered to the page if it wasn't inside a code block. In your case Razor parses your view and returns the result to your code. Since you don't do anything to render it, you don't get the output.

Comment: +1 - Had been trying to work out for a couple of hours why mine wasn't rendering. Such a simple problem!

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing:

```
Html.Partial("Form"); // <- this will return string
```

with:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Form"); // <- writes to response
```

[Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)