# adding custom control in view causes throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Adding custom control in View throws following error: -

```
"\\Views\\Error\\Index.cshtml(9): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult‌​)' has some invalid arguments"
```

Here is the code of index page: -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request. 
</h2>
<div>@Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl")
```

Here is the code of MyUserControl: -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

hi
```

Where as removing `@Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl")` from view renders the page perfectly.

Comment: So... what is the error? Where is the Partial located?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, partial is located in Shared folder

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, it throws following error : - "\\Views\\Error\\Index.cshtml(9): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because of the way you use RenderPartial. You should either do:

```
<div>@Html.Partial("MyUserControl")</div>
```

or

```
<div>@{ Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl");  }</div>
```

[See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction) for additional learning.