# How to show user control in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my user control in a class library and I have a public method in it which returns the user control as html string. I want to display this HTML in my MVC view. I am using the following code in my view:

```
<div>
<% MyControlsNamespace.MyControl mvc = new MyControl();
   mvc.LoadMyControl(); %>
</div>
```

LoadMyControl() returns html as string. I can't see any thing in my view when I open it in a browser. I am new to MVC and I knew I am missing some thing here. Any guess??? I am using MVC1

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not use User Controls in the same was as WebForms. Also note that User Control classes do not contain HTML directly, they're contained within `.ascx` files which are created using `LoadControl`, which doesn't apply to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: What are my best option in this case. I have an ascx user control and I am loading this control using LoadControl() and then rendering this to a string. How can I show this string my my MVC view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<% Html.RenderPartial("Path/To.ascx") %>` or `<%= Html.Partial("Path/To.ascx") %>`.

Use `RenderPartial` when you're fine with the user-control rendering directly to the response stream, or use `Partial` if you want to intercept the output as an MvcHtmlString. `RenderPartial` is faster and generally preferred, only use `Partial` if you know you need the MvcHtmlString.

More information is available here: [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)