# Easiest way to pass data to a partial view FROM a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Code in partial 1 file:

```
 @Html.Partial("Partial2", 50)
```

Code in partial 2 file:

```
@if(passed in parameter == 50)
{
     <div>50 Was Passed In</div>
}
```

Does this really require me to create a new controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx) and [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx) don't require a controller.  [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx) and [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx) require a controller.

So your code in partial 2 should be:

```
@model int

@if(Model == 50)
{
 <div>50 Was Passed In</div>
}
```

Also a good read is [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Answer (score 2):

No, just add the model directive in Partial 2:

```
@model int
@if(Model == 50)
{
     <div>50 Was Passed In</div>
}
```