# How to RenderPartial From View with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to render partialview inside a view with two parameters:

```
1) Viewdata
2) List
```

I am new to MVC4 Razor.
Help me. I don't know how to do it.
I tried this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales", new  {"result_Type",
            ViewData["result_Type"].ToString() });}
```

But it is giving me error.

Comment: First, what the `List` got to do with any of this? Second, the `RenderPartial` helper expects you to pass a model and not an anonymous "routed values object". If `ViewData["result_Type"]` contains the model that your partial view expects, then you should be able to call `@{Html.RenderPartial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales", ViewData["result_Type"]);}`. You should provide additional information such as the error you're getting and maybe the definition of your partial view.

Comment: @AndreiV My partial view represent list of all Doctor Chemist Sales. So I need to pass the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Html.Partial()` helper instead of `Html.RenderPartial()`.

Try:

```
@Html.Partial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales", ViewData);
```

This will render the partial and send through the whole `ViewData`.

If you need to display the items in a list, for example, you can then use:

```
<ul>
    @for (var item in ViewData["myItems"]) // Or whatever your list is called in ViewData
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Although, like @Henk points out in his answer, you're far better off forgetting about `ViewData` and `ViewBag` as a method of getting your data into the views and look into view models.  This will then give you automatic model binding, which will take 90% of the work you're going to potentially encounter if you carry on down the `ViewData/ViewBag` route.

Comment: `Partial` and `RenderPartial` are the same. Except for the fact that `Partial` returns a string and needs the `@` nugget. `RenderPartial`'s return type is `void` as it renders the html directly in the output stream. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such overload of the [`RenderPartial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method where you can specify route parameters. Calling it like this should be enough:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales"); }
```

You can use `ViewData["result_Type"]` in the partial view to get the value. If it doesn't work, you could try and use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470827%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) where you add the ViewData object as an argument:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales", ViewData); }
```

---

You might want to look into [view models](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) in stead of using the ViewData project.

Comment: Well can I pass list too, with viewdata?

Comment: Yes you can, just call `ViewData["result_Type"]` in the partial view and you have access to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
  @Html.Partial("_SelectAllDrChemistSales", ViewData["result_Type"])
```