# how to pass the controller as parameter to other class method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code:

```
 public class StoreController:Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var page=new PageHelper<Store>();          
            return page.PageView(this);
        }
    }   
    public class PageHelper<T>
    {
        public List<T>DataSouce {get;set;}  
        public ActionResult PageView(Controller controller)
        {
            var action = controller.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            if (controller.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                //my question is it can not call the PartialView or controller.View 
                return controller.PartialView(action);               
            return controller.View(DataSource);
        }
    }
```

I can not call the `PartialView` or `controller.View` in `PageView` function.
how I can do it?

now this code:"controller.PartialView(action);" in `PageView` function will be compiled
error. why can not call the View() or PartialView()?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Sorry,I try to format my code,but why can not ok,I had add four space.

Comment: This is because your response is too little descriptive. You can not just put the code in question.

Comment: ok,thank you your help. can you help me with this question?

Comment: yes, are you searching something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction

Comment: explain better your problem and I will answer to your question

Comment: I think my description is very clearly,my question is I can not call"controller.PartialView(action);" in 'PageView(Controller controller)', this code will be compile error.

Comment: can you post the error and the line number?

Comment: I am living in china, as you know we was limited by our government, so I don't know where can i push our demo to us ,can you tell me where can i push it. such as GitHub?

Comment: where do you prefer, GitHub is ok.

Comment: Hi, I push my demo project on our test site.the download url is http://inpromo.vitaminstore.eu/Debug---MVCPager.zip, my email is :chuanhai@kooboo.com, if you have any good suggest,please send message to me.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Is it good?

Comment: I think above your ansow can not solve my question.

Comment: because I have tried an example changing that type and after I was able to see the methods

Comment: can you download my demo, maybe you will be better to understand it.

Comment: I have test your demo and I have changed my answer. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View and PartialView are protected internal methods.

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in
>   which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another
>   assembly.

you should make your class PagerHelper inherit from Controller.

After that you can call inside your PageView method

```
public ActionResult PageView(Controller controller)
    {        
        ViewBag.DataSource = DataSource;
        ViewBag.PageHtml = PageHtml;
        ViewBag.AjaxPageHtml = AjaxPageHtml;

        if (controller.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView(AjaxTag);          
        var action = controller.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        return View(action);         
    }
```

I have tested your project and now it works.

Comment: really? about "class PagerHelper inherit from Controller" I have test it before I submit my question on the stackoverflow. can you send your changes to my email. my email is :chuanhai@outlook.com

Comment: I've tryed to send you the mail but it return back to me with an error (mailbox unavailable).

Comment: Remember that you must not only ensure that the class inherits from Controller. You must also change controller.PartialView with PartialView without controller variable.

Comment: oh, I make a mistake! my Email is: linchuanhai@outlook.com. I'am sorry. can you send it again. I will wating for you online.

Comment: thank you for your mail. I read your changes. but all like your changes I have try it before. of course now It is Compile success. but it can not work. can you run it to see the page result?