# Using a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand how to make partial views. So far I have the following for the partial view, called "_News":

```
@model Site.Services.News.NewsItem

<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-primary">
        <h2>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Title)
        </h2>
    </div>
```

And then in the controller I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<Site.Services.News.NewsItem> - Does this belong here?

...other controller code here...

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    Html.Partial("_News", item);
}
```

But I'm getting "NullReferenceException" when I try to run the application. What am I doing wrong?

Edit as per comments:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader();
        var newsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();


        return View(newsItems);
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your controller code (the 2nd code snippet is not your controller code - its the view code)

Comment: Can you show us the value in Message property in your exception

Comment: No its controller code see edit. There is also no Message property.

Comment: You still have not shown the controller code (that's the view code!). Show the method that generates the view - i.e. `public ActionResult Something() { ... }` in your controller

Comment: Most likely `IEnumerable<Site.Services.News.NewsItem>` is null. How do you assign that value in controller?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I've got the controller in the post now. The whole NewsReader part works fine as I have a specific page for displaying news items and that works correctly, but I'm trying to put a news section within another page by making a partial view to just display the title instead. It just seems to be a problem with using partials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@model Site.Services.News.NewsItem

<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-primary">
     <h2>
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
     </h2>
 </div>
```

There is a syntax error in your code, it should read `model.Title`, not `item.Title` because you are referring to the the model as `model` in the lambda expression.

I.e. this is the same:
`@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Title)`

EDIT:

You also need to put an @ symbol before the `Html.Partial`

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("_News", item);
}
```

See: [Html.Partial not rendering partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448245/html-partial-not-rendering-partial-view)

Comment: That has fixed the exception thanks, but nothing is appearing in the <div> where the partial should be rendered. What could be causing that?

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, are you sure the collection is populated?

Comment: I'm sure it is, I have a news page that displays news posts, which works correctly, and I'm making this partial view to basically display a version of the news on a homepage, I have the same ActionResult for both that and the code in my post. Where should I look to find the problem?

Comment: Yep I totally missed the missing @!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my mistake, I've solved it, I was missing @ on the Html.Partial!

I was surprised that this didn't throw up either an exception or actually display "Html.Partial..." as actual text.

Anyone know why neither of these were the case? If it's not thrown an exception then why wasn't it displayed as plain text?