# ASP.NET MVC HTML Template

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a recurring piece of HTML in my MVC4 project and as I am working on it I have to go through and edit it in each file that uses it.

I am wondering if there is a way to set up some kind of template that just has this small snippet of code and call in it the files where it is needed? It would make editing and debugging much simpler.

Its not a whole page but just a small section that is on certain web pages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should look into partial views.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction

Comment: Partial views did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should absolutely look at the Razor engine and partial views:

http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

A great codebase to look at if you're a quick learner:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC