# Is it preferable to use Html.RenderAction over HTML.Partial and nested View Models to render a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a **ViewModel** that is used for a view. Within that view, I open up a Partial View that is used for one of the HTML tabs that I've put up.

I would like to use another **ViewModel** for that Partial View so at the moment I have a **parent ViewModel** and then have a **child ViewModel**.

Is it better to do it like this or have it completely separated by instead of using `@Html.Partial()`, I should use `@Html.RenderAction`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Comment: OP is not asking difference between two

Comment: The answer in that question clearly answers what the OP needs to ask, also there are many more answers in that question which resolve to this same question :)

Comment: Both render a partial view. It depends if you need to perform some logic to render the partial. If so you would use `@html.Action()` to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` method.

Comment: Note also that if the view is for editing the child view model, then you should not be using a partial but rather an EditorTemplate for the typeof child model (otherwise it will be necessary to pass a `HtmlFieldPrefix` to the partial