# Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction. can any one please describe the difference

Tags: asp.net, renderpartial, renderaction

In ASP.NET MVC, what is the difference between:

```
Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial
Html.Action and Html.RenderAction
```

Comment: i just want to know why we would use one over another?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/), it should answer your question

Comment: In fact I did an answer with short summary of what this link talks about

Comment: thank you so much your link was helpful. but can you how can i implement partial views on one master page, if i have two different partial views and i have included them in "<div>" tag and now i want only one to be visible on selection of particular drop down List option.

Comment: Refer here = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction

Comment: alas the link by Andrei is no longer valid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Html.Action` invokes the controller's action, which means it instantiates the controller entity, calls an action method, which builds a model an returns a view result.

`Html.Partial` uses already created model (or can be called without model at all) to render a specified view.

When to use one over the other? If you already have a model and just want to have a reusable view, opt to `Html.Partial`. If you see that some piece deserves its own model and action, maybe it makes sense to use `Html.Action`.

This question is discussed in much greater details in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120703025920/http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views), and what you see above is basically an excerpt from it.

Comment: alas the link to the article is no longer valid

Comment: @ckapilla, thanks, fixed now. Kudos to awesome wayback machine project