# Using Partial Views in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a HTML file that I want to load using a partial view; however, when I type

```
@Html.P
```

the Partial function never shows up. Did partials get removed in ASP.NET 5 or has it been relocated to a different package? At the moment I'm using the following packages:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4"
```

**Team.html**

```
<!-- Team Section -->
<section id="team" class="bg-light-gray">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Our Amazing Team</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Co-Founder</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Mads Kristensen</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Co-Founder</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>John Papa</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Brady Gaster</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Mike Lorbetske</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>DanielTheCoder</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Naim Hammadi</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team-member">
                    <img src="img/team/2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                    <h4>Tyler Hughes</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Contributor</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <p class="large text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eaque, laboriosam veritatis, quos non quis ad perspiciatis, totam corporis ea, alias ut unde.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Maybe this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction?

Comment: That just shows how it should be used. I've used it before in previous versions of MVC. I'm just redesigning a website and wanted to do it in ASP.NET 5  but I haven't been able to find the Partial function.

Comment: Understood. Have you tried @Html.RenderPartial? Contextually it could make sense. Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show up either. I added the code for my HTML file that I'm trying to load using the partial. There's not really any other code to add because as I said when I type `@Html.P` the Partial and RenderPartial functions are not in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.Partial` is definitely still there. However, I'd recommend using `@await Html.PartialAsync(...)` or `@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync(...) }`.

[image]

The `Html.Partial` method is located in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering` namespace as an `IHtmlHelper` extension in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core` assembly (pulled in by `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`) for beta4.

What you might be seeing is if you type `@Html.` without pressing the `P` immediately the Razor editor will treat the `.` as an end of sentence period until you stop typing for a bit.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I've got the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package in my project.json. Any idea why I'm still not seeing these functions? I also tried to use the functions you suggested but none of them show up. All the Intellisense is suggesting is HTML5 tags.

Comment: @RandomlyKnighted Ignore the Intellisense for a moment and just try to run it. Do you get a compiler or runtime error?