# What is difference between partial and render partial view ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new in asp.net MVC kindly let me know where is should use partial view and where i should Render Partial view . Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Answer (score 9):

[This link might help.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1059778/What-is-Difference-between-Html-Partial-and-Html-R)

**Html.RenderPartial**

1. This method result will be directly written to the HTTP response stream means it used the same TextWriter object as used in the current webpage/template.
2. This method returns void.
3. Simple to use and no need to create any action.
4. RenderPartial method is useful when the displaying data in the partial view is already in the corresponding view model.
5. For example : In a blog to show comments of an article, we would like to use RenderPartial method since an article information with comments are already populated in the view model.
   `@{Html.RenderPartial("_Comments");}`
6. This method is faster than Partial method since its result is directly written to the response stream which makes it fast.

**Html.Partial**

1. Renders the partial view as an HTML-encoded string.
2. This method result can be stored in a variable, since it returns string type value.
3. Simple to use and no need to create any action.
4. Like RenderPartial method, Partial method is also useful when the displaying data in the partial view is already in the corresponding view model.
5. For example: In a blog to show comments of an article, you can use Partial method since an article information with comments are already populated in the view model.
   `@Html.Partial("_Comments")`

Answer (score 0):

Both of these helper method are used for rendering partial views

Both have different syntax in razor view `@Html.Partial("_student", items)` and `{Html.RenderPartial("_student", items);}`, since render partial return void and the output is written directly to output stream, it has different syntax than Partial.

Syntax in web from view
`<%:Html.Partial("_student") %>` and `<% Html.RenderPartial("_student"); %>`

Partial Returns MVCHtmlString, which can be assigned to variables.

Performance wise Render partial is better as it writes directly to output stream.

And of-course you can find a lot of references online and within stack overflow to read