# Join two views MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view that is a menu page:

```
@model SGP.Models.Turma

<h2>MENU</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Ver Notas das Componentes", "AvaliacaoLista", "Turma", new { id = Model.TurmaId }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Ver Notas das SubComponentes", "ListaSubs", "Componente", new { id = Model.TurmaId }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Ver Nota Final", "CalcularNotaFinal", "Turma", new { id = Model.TurmaId }, null)
```

But i would like to show in this same page a table from another model:

```
@model  List<SGP.Models.PessoaModel2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Numero</th>
            @foreach (String s in ViewBag.Componentes)
            {
                <th>@s</th>
            }
            <th>Nota Final</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].turmaId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].userid)
                <td>@Model[i].nome</td>
                <td>@Model[i].num</td>

                @for (int a = 0; a < Model[i].am.Count; a++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].am[a].AvaliacaoId)
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].am[a].nota)</td>
                }           
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Is it possible? The objective is to show this table from PessoaModel2 Model in the menu page from Turma Model. Other way i thought was to turn the menu page into List SGP.Models.PessoaModel2 to put the table but then the links wouldn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways. - e.g. create a view model containing all the properties you need, use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that return the 2nd view.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a Partial View in another view (or partial) with using the `Html.Partial`. Here is another [good resource in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction), beware of the differences between the techniques mentioned in that post..

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the link

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may user `Tuple` class to join to models