# Html.RenderPartial() syntax with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This works, because it returns the result of partial view rendering in a string:

```
@Html.Partial("Path/to/my/partial/view")
```

But I prefer to use `RenderPartial` and it seems I need to write:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view");}
```

instead of:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view");
```

To get it to work. Error message:

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

If there any better way instead of opening code block `@{...}` just for one method call?

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to use `@Html.RenderPartial()`

Comment: I've added message to my post. I understand why it shows an error @Html.RenderPartial() is parsed as roughly as <%?:@Html.RenderPartial() ?> which is wrong and not as <? Html.RenderPartial(); ?>, but I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Related: [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction). BTW why do you prefer to use `RenderPartial`?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

- `RenderPartial()` is a *void method* that writes to the response stream. A void method, in C#, needs a `;` and hence must be enclosed by `{ }`.
- `Partial()` is a method that returns an [MvcHtmlString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293357/what-is-an-mvchtmlstring-and-when-should-i-use-it/2293662#2293662). In Razor, You can call a property or a method that returns such a string with just a `@` prefix to distinguish it from plain HTML you have on the page.

Comment: Why do you prefer using Html.RenderPartial instead of Html.Partial? If you, from some reason, want/need to go with Html.RenderPartial, there is no workaround - that's the syntax.

Comment: I use it because it should be more effective (because it doesn't return huge string).

Answer (score 45):

Html.RenderPartial() is a void method - you can check whether a method is a void method by placing your mouse over the call to RenderPartial in your code and you will see the text *(extension) void HtmlHelper.RenderPartial...*

Void methods require a semicolon at the end of the calling code.

In the Webforms view engine you would have encased your Html.RenderPartial() call within the bee stings <% %>

like so

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view"); %>
```

when you are using the Razor view engine the equivalent is

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view");}
```

Comment: "bee stings" -- that's a first (for me?)

Answer (score 10):

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfPartialView")
```

Comment: I'd like to use `Html.RenderPartial()`, that's why I asked this question. The details: "Performance-wise, it's been claimed that rendering directly to the output stream is better (which was why they went w/ the void RenderPartial to start with)." from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2729851/118810

Answer (score 0):

If you are given this format it takes like a link to another page or another link.partial view majorly used for renduring the html files from one place to another.