# Exception raised on returning PartialView from mvc4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a asp.net mvc4 view which includes some partial views. This view also contains a submit button to filter some elements in the grid, see below:

Configure.cshtml

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    @Html.Partial("../Grids/_CompGrid")
</div>

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Component", ...)
 {
     <input type="submit" name="_search" value="@Resource.CaptionComponentApplyFilter" />
 }
```

ComponentController.cs

```
    public PartialViewResult Search()
    {
        // Do some stuff

        return PartialView("_CompGrid");
    }
```

When returning the partial view above indicated it crashes. It seems like it is not handling the correct path to the partial view. See below message error:

```
The partial view '_CompGrid' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Component/_CompGrid.aspx
~/Views/Component/_CompGrid.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.ascx
~/Views/Component/_CompGrid.cshtml
~/Views/Component/_CompGrid.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.vbhtml
```

Below the directory structure overview of the above files indicated.

```
/root
  |
  |__ Controllers
  |       |
  |       |__ ComponentController.cs
  |
  |__ Views
  |       |
  |       |__ Home
  |       |     | 
  |       |     |__ Configure.cshtml
  |       |
  |       |__ Grids
  |       |     |
  |       |     |__ _CompGrid.cshtml
  |       |
  |       |
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

**SOLUTION:**

Replace below return line in the function:

```
    public PartialViewResult Search()
    {
        // Do some stuff

        return PartialView("_CompGrid");
    }
```

by:

```
return PartialView("../Grids/_CompGrid");
```

but anyway if someone has a better idea, it will be welcome.

Comment: It seems I have just solved it by replacing the returning line by: return PartialView("../Grids/_CompGrid"); but If someone have any better idea, please make suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options really.  Firstly, you could simply reference the partial using `~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.cshtml`.  That will always work from the root of the `Views` folder, so it'll be more obvious how to fix it if your folder structure gets changed.

Your other option would be to put the partial into the `~/Views/Shared/` folder, because it is one of the default search locations when MVC is attempting to locate a view.  (You can actually see this from the error you provided above.)  So, assuming you moved `_CompGrid.cshtml` to be located at `~/Views/Shared/_CompGrid.cshtml`, the following code would locate your view correctly:

ComponentController:

```
public PartialViewResult Search()
{
    // Do some stuff

    return PartialView("_CompGrid");
}
```

Configure.cshtml:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    @Html.Partial("_CompGrid")
</div>
```

Comment: One further note, `Html.RenderPartial` is better, performance-wise, when compared with `Html.Partial`.  This is also true of `Html.RenderAction` vs `Html.Action`.  See [here](http://5pm.zwares.com/post/1172669451/asp-net-mvc-performance-html-renderpartial-vs) for details.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment about RenderPartial and RenderAction: it's great! I would like to mention that the syntax of Html.RenderPartial must be between enclosed with {} and using a semicolon, for example, in my case:  @{Html.RenderPartial("../Grids/_CompGrid");} See below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980823/html-renderpartial-syntax-with-razor and also for differences between them see here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729815/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-html-partialview-model-and-html-rende/2729851#2729851

Comment: your first solution does not work: I have replaced return ('../Grids/_CompGrid') by return ('~Views/Grids/_CompGrid') and below error is thrwon: +  [System.InvalidOperationException] {"The partial view '~Views/Grids/_CompGrid' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~Views/Grids/_CompGrid"} System.InvalidOperationException –

Comment: @user1624552 Sorry, I forgot the `.cshtml.` must be included when using the `~`.  Also, I was missing the first `/` too.  Updated to correct those.