# Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am totally confused even after seeing the following explanation.

```
<div>
  @Html.Partial("_FeaturedProduct")
</div>
```

Partial views can be rendered inside a Layout Page (or if using MVC 2/3 w/ASPX, the Master Page) as well as regular views.

There are some cases where you might like to step aside and write directly to the HTTP Response stream rather than having a partial view render the results (partials/views use MvcHtmlString/StringWriter). To do so, use the Html.RenderPartial helper.

```
<div>
  @Html.RenderPartial("_FeaturedProduct")
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what it means? What cases where I might like to write direct to the HTTP Response etc.   What if my partial view contains just one line like this:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Which should I use and why? What would happen if I used the other?

The following confused me even more: "Use Html.RenderPartial for streaming images or other elements that are media-centric or where faster download times are highly important."

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference (if any) between Html.Partial(view, model) and Html.RenderPartial(view,model) in MVC2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729815/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-html-partialview-model-and-html-render)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the response below.

> The only difference is that Partial returns an MvcHtmlString, and must
>   be called inside <%= %>, whereas RenderPartial returnsvoid and renders
>   directly to the view.
>
> If you look at the source code, you'll see that they both call the
>   same internal method, passing a StringWriter for it to render to.
>
> You would call Partial if you want to view, save, or manipulate the
>   generated HTML instead of writing it to the page.

[What is the difference (if any) between Html.Partial(view, model) and Html.RenderPartial(view,model) in MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729815/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-html-partialview-model-and-html-render)