# ASP.NET Razor: How do I render a Razor Partial to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Render Partial View into a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string)

I am looking to render a Partial in my C# code to string, does anyone know how I can achieve this? The partial is just a good old partial that sits in the Partials directory and will not be used by anything else.

Comment: Check this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537741/how-to-render-partial-view-into-a-string

Answer (score 1):

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Also refer: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

Answer (score 0):

You can Use HTML.Partial which returns an MvcHtmlString, now on that you can use a ToString() method and so you get a string. Do not confuse with HTML.RenderPartial();

[Html.Partial or Html.RenderPartial with MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371348/html-partial-or-html-renderpartial-with-mvc3)

Comment: as I mentioned, I need to render it in C#, not in the view

Comment: Yes, you can use the HtmlHelper Class anywhere in your code as long as you have a reference to System.Web.Mvc .

Comment: This method does not appear in my IntelliSense