# asp.net mvc partial view errors out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

My partial view, called _myTestView.cshtml

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">

TEST

</div>
```

I call it like that

```
<div>
  @Html.RenderPartial("_myTestView");
</div>
```

I get the following run time error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not inside a code block, so you  don't use `.RenderPartial`

Just use `.Partial` and get rid of the `;`

```
<div>
  @Html.Partial("_myTestView")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside a code block

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_myTestView");}
```

related [What is the difference (if any) between Html.Partial(view, model) and Html.RenderPartial(view,model) in MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2729815/40822)