# ASP.NET MVC - Why don't HtmlHelpers render directly to the stream?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why do ASP.NET MVC HTML Helpers return MvcHtmlString instances? It seems rather inefficient to allocate a string for each rendered helper in a page. Why don't Helpers work the same way as WebForms Controls by rendering directly to a HtmlTextWriter?

Comment: Note that you are generally allocating strings even when you are just outputting them to a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC Views can be used not only to produce HTML, but as a templating system used, for example, to produce e-mails. You will easily find here, on StackOverflow, method to render view directly to string. This also gives you easier possibility to test your views.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a string allows you to potentially do more with it, or to call them in other places (such as helper classes).

If you want the perf, there *are* versions of some of them that write directly, such as `RenderPartial()`. See this stack overflow question: [Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

edit: and this one: [What is the difference (if any) between Html.Partial(view, model) and Html.RenderPartial(view,model) in MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729815/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-html-partialview-model-and-html-rende)