# Why does Html.Action fail the second time it's called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have this action method on `ProjectAuthorityController`:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BoqReview(Guid projectId)
{
    var model = GetReviewModel(projectId);
    return PartialView("_BoqReviewPartial", model);
}
```

Then in my main view, `BoqUpload`, I have the following Razor element:

```
@Html.Action("BoqReview", "ProjectAuthority", new { projectId = Model.ProjectId })
```

When my `BoqUpload` view renders a second time, after the `BoqUpload` POST action completes, I get the following error on the `@Html.Action` element:

```
A public action method 'BoqReview' was not found on controller 'ITIS.Web.Modules.ProjectAuthority.Controllers.ProjectAuthorityController'.
```

Now how can this view find the public method 'BoqReview' the first time the view renders, and not the second time?

Comment: Wheres the calling code?

Comment: do projectId contain value both times?

Comment: this link may same issue with you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941317/a-public-action-method-was-not-found-on-controller

Comment: @LasseEdsvik Yes, but even it doesn't, the action should still work, it should just get data for a different project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `[HttpGet]` annotation

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult BoqReview(Guid projectId)
{
    var model = GetReviewModel(projectId);
    return PartialView("_BoqReviewPartial", model);
}
```