# A public action method 'subscriber' was not found on controller 'NewsletterController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am getting this error as a warning from the elmah error log.
Actually I have no method on controller named "subscriber".
I have explored this solutions also

[A public action method '..' was not found on controller '..'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941317/a-public-action-method-was-not-found-on-controller)

But all the issue is I haven't method called "subscriber" in my controller.

Here is my Newsletter controller.

```
  public class NewsletterController : Controller
    {
        private readonly NewsletterService _newsletterService;

        public NewsletterController(NewsletterService newsletterService)
        {
            _newsletterService = newsletterService;
            ;
        }

        [Route("newsletter/sign-up")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SignUp(NewsletterSignUpModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _newsletterService.SignUp(model);
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

`_newsletterService.SignUp()` this method calls the [campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/) to subscribe the user.

Elmah error log says [image: here]

I have searched in project for particular url "newsletter/subscriber/new" and also separate words. but nothing found.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: The the log is accurate.

Comment: Someone or something tried to request that URL and it does not exist, so error was logged.

Comment: could you try clean the solution and rebuild it?

Comment: Clean and rebulid tried many times , In local I am not getting any issue. I am getting that on live only